# iPad JavaScript onchange onblur not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

I have this code:

```
<form method="Post" action="http://....." name="chginv">
    Inventory:
    <select id="inventory" onchange="chgInv()" name="inventory" title="Choose an Inventory">
        <option selected="" value="option 1">1</option>
        <option value="option 2">2</option>
        <option value="option 3">3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and the JavaScript function is simply:

```
function chgInv() {
    document.forms["chginv"].submit();
}
```

It works in Chrome, Firefox, IE on WIndows yet fails on Chrome and Safari  on an iPad.

I have ensured the popup blocker is turned off in both browsers on the iPad.

What is going on here?

I read an article on here about something similar and that article suggested using onblur, so I did, with the same result, nothing happening! :-(

I hope someone can help.

thanks

Ken

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="Post" action="http://....." name="chginv" id="chginv" >
```

**or**

```
document.chginv.submit();
```

should fix ya lemme know if it does not

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, no, it has had no effect. :-(

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem try changing to `document.getElementById("chginv").submit();`  if that does not work open it in chrome, inspect element and go to console tab see if you get an error in there

Comment: getElementById din't work either.

How do I inspect element on the iPad.  All 3 options worked under windows so I am not seeing any errors there.

I have also tried Opera on the iPad, same result.

I added an alert just before the submit call and that doesn't happen on the iPad either.

I am about to check another iPad, just in case!

Comment: Tried on Chrome on an iPad Mini, same result :-(

Comment: misread thought it was not working on chorme or an ipad with safari. http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/07/enable-safari-debug-console-ios/ will walk you through starting debug console on your ipad

Comment: That only works if you have Safari on a Mac.  I cannot get it to work on the Windows version of Safari.  I also tried firebug Lite but it doesn't work on iOS7+ and development is currently halted due to lack of resources :-(